# How can I change the value of a destructured object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I'm learning react by following a guide, but it's outdated. I want to change the value of 'weight' that is inside the person object, but whenever I toggle the onChange I get an error that says "person.setState is not a function."

```
 const person = {
    weight : '',
  };
  
  const { weight } = person;
  
  const handleClick = (event) => {
      person.setState({weight : event.target.value});
      console.log(person);
  }
  
  return( 
        //  <button onClick = {(event) => console.log(objectData.inputText)}>Button</button>
        <input placeholder='weight' onChange={handleClick}></input>
  )
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense either for a class component or a function component. `person.setState` is wrong. Where are you setting up state? That's not in your code.

Comment: I was following the example online, he had his set to state. I'm assuming mine should be set to 'setPerson' instead of 'setState'?

Comment: I've been using react hooks before this, so I feel like I'm getting the information I have on both a little messed up

Comment: where is your useState btw?

Answer (score 0):

If you're following a tutorial for function components your code should probably look like this.

1. Use the `useState` hook to initialise state (as an empty string).
2. Use the state function `setWeight` to update the state.
3. Perhaps call your handler a more appropriate name (`handleChange` rather than `handleClick`).

I've included a separate paragraph that shows the changes in the state as you change the input value.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ weight, setWeight ] = useState('');

  function handleChange(e) {
    setWeight(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <input
        placeholder="weight"
        value={weight}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <p>{weight}</p>
    </section>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

If you wanted an object (`person`) as the initialised state the code is slightly different.

1. Your input should have a `name` attribute
2. Your handler should destructure the name and value from `e.target`.
3. Your `setPerson` callback should take the previous state, and spread it out into a new object, using the name and value to add a new property key/value.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ person, setPerson ] = useState({ weight: '' });

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setPerson(prev => {
      return { ...prev, [name]: value };
    });
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <input
        name="weight"
        placeholder="weight"
        value={person.weight}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <p>{person.weight}</p>
    </section>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: So the tutorial I've seen has used hooks before, but he is also able to change the value of a destructured object by using 'this.setState' on the onChange in his input field. That is what I am trying to do. So basically, change 'weight' to whatever is inside the input field.

Comment: If the tutorial is using `this.setState` then it's a tutorial for a class component, and no good if you're using hooks in a function component. @TheTargetAudience. It was unclear from your code what you were using which is why I asked in my first comment.

Comment: Apologies for not metioning that. Would my solution be to siwtch to a Class component and working with that?

Comment: The solution is to pick one that you're happy with, and then follow a tutorial for that style. I can add a class component example to my answer if you'd like - to cover all bases :) @TheTargetAudience

Comment: I actually was able to figure out how to do it. I have enough experience with class components from following the tutorial, but I appreciate the offer. For now I'll just work on function components. I apprecaite the help!